# Does John Ringo actually endorse the political views expressed in Troy Rising?

Tags: politics, john-ringo, troy-rising

I recently read John Ringo's military sci-fi series, *Troy Rising*, and some of the political views expressed by characters were ... surprising, to put it politely. Some of these include:

- Well, even if Earth loses most of its Islamic population, it really does not matter.
- The world secretly feels glad that the US plays international policeman.
- The 'West' is the guardian of free speech and personal freedom against the orthodoxy of the 'East'.

Does John Ringo actually endorse such views, or did he just create one-sided characters? Also, are similar views expressed in any of his other books?

Comment: What's next, does Kiefer Sutherland practice torture in his spare time?

Comment: @Gaius - He's been torturing us with his terrible acting for a couple of decades

Comment: Similar threads are in *The Last Centurion*, some also surface in *The Empire of Man*, so it's almost a given he endorses them.. But besides the fact that I would not call these views political, they're hardly surprising. They may be unpopular, may be very offensive, but not surprising. We, as a modern societies, just buried a mountain of literature that expressed these sentiments for quite a long time before 1980s... Seems like no one reads Churchill or Kipling anymore, for example....

Comment: @Gaius I don't know if the question is on-topic here, but it's not so easily dismissed. Many scifi authors have their ideology permeate their works; Ursula K. LeGuin and Heinlein are a couple of obvious examples...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on [this interview](http://michaelaventrella.com/2011/02/18/interview-with-new-york-times-bestselling-author-john-ringo/) on the Michael Ventrella website, I think that it's reasonably obvious that Ringo's views are largely the same as those expressed by his characters:

> **VENTRELLA:** *Have you ever run across unexpected controversy with your writing? If so, how have you dealt with it?*
>
> **RINGO:** *Unexpected? No. I’m considered a ‘controversial conservative SF author.’ Not to mention GHOST, which… well, you just don’t get more controversial unless you’re a gangsta rappah under indictment for murder. How do I deal with it? Generally I try to swallow my rage and smile. **Because with the exception of some of the stuff in the Ghost series, I really don’t see what I say, what my characters do and say, as particularly controversial, crazy, evil or illogical. I see the people who consider it ‘controversial’ as idiots and morons.** (Whereas they view me as a ‘racist, homophobic, xenophobic, genocidal asshole’ in the words of Mercedes Lackey.)*
>
> *So, mostly, I ignore it.*
>
> **VENTRELLA:** *You’ve never shied away from political issues as well (nor have I) – we have had a few interesting discussions in this area. Do you think it is wise for authors to take stands which may alienate readers?*
>
> **RINGO:** *As I said in a recent email to a family member, politics has become religion and there is virtually nothing which is not politicized. You can take the PC approach of having the enemy be alter versions of what the Left hates (the US military as in Avatar, Christians, middle-class white males) in which case you can alienate the core readers of SF. Or you can alienate the Left by being a human and American exceptionalist and having characters who, whatever their race, nationality, creed or sex, act in a traditional self-determinant manner and worry about PC after the Human Race has been saved.*

Comment: Yeah, I went "ah well" for (what Mercedes put), but kinda tossed all his stuff when the rape, bonadage, and other S&M crap wandered out of Paladin of Shadows and into the Council Wars.  At that point I started wondering if dementia was disinhibiting him.

Comment: Ringo has a tendency of having the plot come to a screeching halt so a character can go a long long rambling discourse about some topic utterly unrelated to what is going on in the book, so there will be absolutely no question what Ringo thinks about the subject. I also note with amusement his assumption that the "core" SF audience is white, Christian, middle-class males.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - Assumptions can often be quite accurate; https://lelaebuis.wordpress.com/2019/01/09/so-who-reads-science-fiction-anyway/

Comment: @Valorum, I've seen "conservative" authors proceed to spiral into isolation because they assume that will forever be the case (not that I trust those stats given there anyway). Not to mention one of the studies referenced there implies Engineering is not an applied discipline, which immediately calls into question the entire thesis if they can't figure out engineering is THE prototypical applied discipline.

Comment: @Valorum - The page that you linked cites a study showing that a *slight* majority of SF readers are male (57%). How is that equivalent to saying that the core audience of SF is male *and* white *and* Christian *and* middle-class?

Comment: "Ringo has a tendency of having the plot come to a screeching halt so a character can go a long long rambling discourse about some topic utterly unrelated to what is going on in the book":  a narrative tradition in the style of Starship Troopers.  There's like a 10 (?) page diatribe about beating your children in the middle of a military sci-fi.

Comment: @KeithMorisson Read the link again: the implication is just the opposite; it’s clear _it_ knows for its Business Insider link that engineering _is_ an applied science: “ For example, liberals tend to like theoretical disciplines including anthropology, biology, astronomy, physics and (surprise) engineering. On the other hand, conservatives tend to prefer applied disciplines including medicine, law and (surprise) climate change.” The “_surprises_” here are precisely the counter conclusion: liberals love theoretical science but eng & cons love applied eng but climate change (highly theoretical)

Comment: I agree with this answer but I would add this: the reason we're talking about Ringo or about any SF&F author is because they're good story tellers. They decided to take months or years to write this or that book for their own reasons. Maybe they like to have a mix of characters, some liberal and some conservative or some, God help us, both. That's reality. The world ain't simple. 
But is it a good story? That's why it's being read.

Answer (score 10):

Having read a few of Ringo's books, including the entire [Paladin of Shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paladin_of_Shadows) series and a few books from the [Legacy of the Aldenata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Aldenata) series, I can say that Ringo pretty consistently assigns such views to his main characters. As a matter of fact, the list of views you provided is just the tip of the iceberg!

I will not comment on any of the more *interesting* views in Ringo's books, since I doubt I can do so politely and without inciting a war. I will point out, however, that authors *usually* put a bit of themselves in their work. I think that Ringo's books don't have the feel of intentional exaggeration of flaws used by some authors, so at this point I believe that he must agree to a degree with these ideas, although possible not to the extreme extent indicated by his books.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that Ringo *could* just be a good enough writer that his exaggerations are seamless.

Comment: @Jeff: His exaggerations may be seamless, but they're also remarkably consistent across many books. No doubt, the real John Ringo is in there.  "Ghost" is a pretty good example.

Comment: @Tynam: Ghost was originally titled 'The Wank Piece' and he didn't want to publish it.  He also very much agrees with the 'Oh John Ringo, NO' thing the stories created.  He may very well hold the beliefs his characters espouse, but then again Katya does a pretty good send-up of them in one of the later Paladin of Shadows books.

Comment: @Jeff: I didn't say he wasn't *good* at it.  The real Ringo is in there, but he's self-aware enough be able to hang a lampshade on it when he wants.  (Many bits of the Ghost series are good examples of him exaggerating the characters until they break... but there's definitely some actual Ringo as the starting point.)

Comment: @Jeff  To quote from above " you can alienate the Left by being a human "

Answer (score -1):

I also agree that John is expressing his views through the mouth of his characters.

Another example of his views is made pretty clear in the Vorpal Blade series, where one of the Middle Eastern countries imports some genetic material from the Dreen, which has the long term effect of pretty much wiping out all life in the Middle East.  I certainly felt he was "tidying up a loose end" in his world setting. To me it feels plain that he has little respect for the culture that exists in Islam.

While I may not have his view myself, I think a reader should always go into his books knowing that he will likely have a strong view on the success of a meritocracy, the wisdom of democracy, and the efficiacy of free-market capitalism.  In some respects, I think that is part of the appeal of his writing, he is unashamedly proud and his stories come across almost as if they were/ are larger than life in the same way a graphic novel is.  They are not only larger than life, they are also in some parts slightly two-dimensional.

Rollicking good tales though!  Brilliant world creation, and fascinating ideas.  Even with the danger the Dreen represent, it would be SO COOL to have Chen Anomolies, looking glasses, to explore the universe with.  Even with the challenges the Posleen create - some aspects of the Aldenata world would be intriguing to say the least.

This page [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TroyRising) at tvtropes does a fairly good job of giving insight into his style, and a bit of his thinking. There are spoilers - but they are masked.

One of the characteristic style elements of his writing, is a dry fairly in-your-face often black humour.  If you enoy one of his books, you'll likely enjoy them all.  Just don't take his views to much too heart ;-)  (DO take them seriously - he does mean them!)

Answer (score -1):

*The Last Centurion* by John Ringo is even more "egregious" in this regard. But similar sentiments can be also found in (mentioned by others, too):

1. *Paladin of Shadows* series
2. *The Looking Glass series* (a.k.a. Voyage of the Space Bubble)
3. *The Empire of Man series* (though that one, as a co-written with David Weber is somewhat toned).
4. *Legacy of the Aldenata* series
5. *Von Neumann's War*

As I mentioned in the comment elsewhere, I would not call Ringo's world-view political. But I may be an old-timer for that, who doesn't look at everything through politics.

And I would not call them surprising. Well, maybe for younger audiences they may be, but there is a veritable mountain of literature expressing similar, if not even more "outrageous", views. It's just modern society buried it in the name of currently fashionable world-view, which has serious issues with coping with differing ideas, opinions or even facts.

To illustrate this to the commenters, here is the actual title of an article (and actual link below):
***‘Fascist’ Anti-Vax Riot Sparks COVID Outbreak in Australia—With Rupert Murdoch’s Help***
https://www.thedailybeast.com/fascist-anti-vax-riot-sparks-covid-outbreak-in-australiawith-rupert-murdochs-help

How can one protest state vaccine mandate and be called fascist is beyond me... Joking, of course, this is exactly what Ringo writes about in his works.

But what gets me, really, is the number of people who literally deny this phenomenon ever happening.

Comment: "currently fashionable world-view, which has serious issues with coping with differing ideas" doesn't seem like a very constructive remark, and also isn't really applicable to Ringo's political views (whatever they may be).  And are you seriously suggesting that modern disapproval/revulsion of sexism and racism (among others) is merely "fashion?"

Comment: @DavidW - no, I am suggesting that modern society has lapsed into a habit of shutting out of the discussion not only ideas or opinions but also facts which do not conform to the commonly accepted views. It is so bad now that what is presented as anti-sexist and anti-racist (among others) is exactly sexism and racism. It used to be commonly accepted that nazism was bad, and "Mein Kampf" was widely available for people to know why. Now, nazism makes a come back into politics and most of the supporters of it's proponents don't even know it, because if you read Hitler you're a nazi.

Comment: @DavidW - and this is not in connection with Ringo's work, but in connection to the question. I'm addressing here statements made by OP, who chose to characterize Ringo's views in such a way, and I pointed out that characterization is incorrect, with explanation why.

Comment: @DavidW see edited answer.

Comment: Your logic here seems to be that there is some "default" set of views, to which you and John Ringo ascribe, and only _deviations_ from that should be considered "political". That's not really how the world works; whether you like it or not, lots of people _don't_ hold those views, and are just as entitled you to comment on the differences.

Comment: @IMSoP Please read the question carefully. And then my answer. Whenever I - or Ringo for that matter - assert we're right? Where, for that matter, I am indicating my views in my answer? I merely point out that OP chose to classify J.R.'s opinion in specific way and I pointed out this classification is incorrect. I am sorry to say You seem to be exactly the person my edit is about...

Comment: @AcePL It's the "classification is incorrect" part that I'm challenging. It's like saying "Roman Catholicism isn't a denomination, it's the normal church; only the others are denominations".

Comment: To clarify, I'm particularly talking about the idea that a world view can "not be political". The "surprising" part is obviously a lot more subjective. Also, to be clear, I absolutely don't deny that there are equally extreme *political views* on the other end of the spectrum, like the website you linked to, and the word "fascist" is definitely brought out too readily by many liberals, just as "communist" is brought out too readily by many conservatives. I don't think that has much bearing on the definition of "political views", though.

Comment: @IMSoP And again you are arguing with things I didn't say - I said his views aren't political, but that's me. Because it may also be cultural... What I'm pointing out - and you seem to miss that - is not the fact that someone overuses fascist and communist description... I'm pointing out that someone protesting state vaccine mandate is BY DEFINITION ANTI-FASCIST. This is what I'm getting at here - that someone's views may be POLITICALLY INCORRECT, which OP implies about Ringo, and I take exception to that, with pointing out that Ringo MAKES AN ARGUMENT in favor of his opinions, as well.

Comment: @IMSoP As am I with mine, and had people simply allowed for diversity of opinion my views, such as I indicate in limited fashion,  would not be surprising. However, for the time being what Ringo is proposing is for all practical purposes labelled wrong, and my example underscores the fact that it's because labellers are undereducated or purposefully mislead...

Comment: @AcePL I think you are the one reading things that aren't there. The question doesn't say anything about "political correctness", it mentions "political views" - that is, "views which are about or related to politics".

Comment: @IMSoP Qualifying them as "surprising, to put it politely" means something, and unless I miss my mark by a wide margin, i understood correctly what that something is.