Space Invasion story. People get a blister, or pimple on their arm. Treated, they are fine, untreated they die
I recall a novel published maybe 20-30 years ago.
I don't know if the aliens are actually on the planet (like the "V" series) or alien visitors are spreading plagues.
People all over the world suddenly get a blister or pimple on their hand, wrist, or arm. Most people normally would treat it (wash with soap & water, or alcohol wipes, or ointments, or band-aids). Anyone who did this survives.  Anyone who ignored it ends up dying. (It was targeted at people who would not treat it, homeless, poor, drug users, anyone who this would not seem like a big deal to because they had other problems to worry about.) Everyone had it in the same location, but it was minor so no one really did much else. But once people realized everyone had it in the same place, it was obviously artificially induced.)
I think they also spread a plague that targeted women. The fertility and sex drive of (blue-eyed blondes)? was increased. Most ended up having babies back to back to back. And maybe the rest of the woman might have reduced sex drive and fertility.
[I am not sure if this was the same book, or another book I am thinking of.]

This is a sub-plot (the overall disease suite is called Johannsen's Syndrome) found in the Troy Rising series by John Ringo. (2010 - 2011)
The series is set in the early days of human-alien contact, with humans forced to defend the Earth from the alien invasion.
The Horvath (the bad guys) seed Earth with diseases intended to weed out "weaker" humans to eventually turn the planet into a slave worker source with a constantly renewing base of people by making women much more fertile. So not less fertile or reduced sex drive but rather the reverse.

Live Free or Die
Citadel
The Hot Gate


"All of the organisms are tailored for specific tasks. The nematode is designed to sort for persons who are lazy or sloppy. One might go so far as to say stupid."


"There is a virus loaded to eliminate a host of genetic disorders including color blindness. Then one that attacks anyone with a reduced immune system. One that eliminates anyone with genetic propensity for cancer or several auto-immune disorders such as lupus. Then one that attacks several teratogenic conditions."


"Which are all very much overkill because the last one kills anyone who does not have a gene for blond hair."


The effect had been studied and, to the sometimes amusement of males, it turned out that the ‘heat’ effect was functionally identical to male arousal. Just more varied. For about seven days during the four week cycle, essentially during their menstruation period, women had about normal arousal. During the remaining three weeks they were, in the oft quoted words of some medical pundit, ‘Seventeen year old males with choice.'


Is it the evil aliens who are creating these bizarre viruses? They seem intended to "improve" humanity, albeit with a rather Nazi view of improvement.

Yes, the Horvath intended to reduce the population with a view to improving the remainder for slave worker type purposes.

It would undoubtedly be churlish of me to question why interstellar aliens would need biological slaves versus machine automation, or whether these varied diseases would actually be particularly useful at accomplishing that goal, or whether certain elements might have sprung from the author's juvenile fantasies, but I am curious as to why the aliens only like blond people. Are they just really racist aliens?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No need. If you haven't read the books this is only a minor point in a much larger arc regarding space mining, giant asteroid battle stations etc. I'd suggest you read them for more context if you haven't.... I enjoyed them immensely.

The "blister or pimple" is described as "a lesion on the inside of the left wrist".

As soon as I saw the mention of blondes, I knew the book. It's part of one of the slightly more controversial aspects of the book, where the elimination of particular races (Arabs, among others) is treated by the protagonist as a mixed blessing because it also rids humanity of some people sowing dissent along humanity when they need to be united.

Dupe target of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191048/looking-for-the-title-of-a-book-about-alien-invasion-mining-asteroids-and-using?noredirect=1&lq=1 although it's two other linked answers that mention the disease.

FWIW, the plot line of races wiped out in Ringo's works came up as the topic of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/does-john-ringo-actually-endorse-the-political-views-expressed-in-troy-rising

Yes this is the one I was thinking of.. Thanks.

@FuzzyBoots - I'm sure that Ringo has the aliens wipe out everyone but blond sex fiends for perfectly good plot reasons that have nothing to do with his personal fantasies!

@Adamant he doesn't. The attacks largely failed because humanity was already familiar with the potential for such things before contact. The only real effect was to wipe out groups that refused to use modern medicine like vaccines and basic wound sterilization. If you want to criticize the books, criticize the actual books, not some fantasized version of them.
